# Visualize the architecture of a neural network with custom layers

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Is there any way to see the architecture of a neural network with custom layers?

I'm using a model that contains a **custom position encoding**, then a `keras_nlp.layers.TransformerEncoder` layer, and finally the classic `GlobalAveragePooling1D` and `Dense` layers.

I have tried with Keras Visualizer but I get the following error:

```
keras visualizer: layer not supported for visualizing
```

I guess it's because the custom layer.

The `model.summary()` gives me the correct data of my model, but I would like to see the architecture of the neural network similar to the following photo:

[image: Keras Visualizer]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.